# NSString outofscope issue

Tags: iphone

My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.dateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",appDelegate.tappedDate];
    dateLabel.text=dateString;
}

-(IBAction)checkForData:(id)sender{
    NSString *bday=@"2012-01-26";
    if(bday==dateString)
    {
        UIAlertView *bdayView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Birthday!!!" message:@"Its ur Best Friend's Bday" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [bdayView show];
        [bdayView release];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *bdayView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Data" message:@"No Data available for this date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [bdayView show];
        [bdayView release];
    }
}
```

The String dateString is going out of scope in the if condition but it is displaying data on the label.

Comment: the appDelegate.tappedDate is going out of scope.

Comment: You know that you can't compare two NSStrings with `==`? You have to use `isEqualToString:`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `bday` will never equal `dateString`, as `==` compares the addresses of both objects. If you want to compare the actual strings, you need to do `if ([bday isEqualToString:dateString]) {...}`

Regarding the out-of-scope message: How does the property for `dateString` look like? You need to provide more details. Commonly, it should look like `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dateString`